# GestureOverlayView is blocking touch events

Tags: android, events, touch

I wish to create a custom view for my gestures, I wish to draw them by my self.

But I do not getting touch events, or I am getting them and the GestureOverlayView not.

Can you help me please making us both getting all the touch events?

Answer (score -1):

You can ovveride the onTouchEvent method like this

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
// Your code here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you might be doing a silly mistake i was doing previously. dont take gestureOverlayView parallely to views you want touchables, but take those views as child of gestureOverLayView.

what you should not do

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
            android:id="@+id/gOverlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"
            android:fadeOffset="1000"
            android:gestureColor="@color/gesture_color"
            android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
            android:uncertainGestureColor="@color/gesture_color" >
        </android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/customtab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

What you should do..

```
    <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
        android:id="@+id/gOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"
        android:fadeOffset="1000"
        android:gestureColor="@color/gesture_color"
        android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
        android:uncertainGestureColor="@color/gesture_color" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/customtab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
```